# Saving changes to DB made in a webpage

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, crud

I rewrote the title and content 3 times before posting it, I don't find the right way to ask this :P

I have a page that manage a list of notes, I have a CRUD on that page but the items are created and saved in javascript (using knockoutjs).

I create a new note, I add it to the model in javascript and it show up in the page.

The way Im saving the notes to the database is when I add it to the model, I send it via Ajax (async) to the server. So I have my note on screen and in the database really fast.

I send a note without Id to the server and EF will take care of the Id.

So far so good.

Imagine that I add a note but I dont refresh the webpage, so the note is in the database, is in the javascript model too but in the model it doesn't have the id yet.

I make some changes to the note and yeah, I want to update the note in the database... but... how?

I send my note to the server with the changes, but remember, the item still have no Id so I can't say:

Hey EF, give me the note with the ID == xx and we are going to update that note.

The others properties can be changed on the webpage so I have nothing that identifies the note apart from the Id, who doesn't work here.

I tried this:

Send the new note to the server, insert it on the database, retrieve it again (to pick the Id), send it back to javascript and update the object with the Id. So when I edit, I have the Id. Yeah, but the "save" call need to be sync and that destroy the experience.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: The sync options is not that slow at the end but there have to be a async way and meh, the thing of "Insert on database", "Retrieve the last item I inserted" and "return back to the client" is a little hackish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the id of the new record in your asynch call. If you are using jQuery you can  subscribe to the "success" callback and as long as your controller returns a JSON with the id of the new record you could update your model on the client side.

Even with this approach, you will need to have a way to identify the item updated on the client side (which is really the root of your question.) For that you can probably generate a random GUID on the client side, send it to the server when saving, and return it to jQuery when returning the ID so that you can identify the correct element to update on the page.

Comment: I resolved it, almost the same idea. I send async the new item and I return the id back to the client, the save function in javascript had the item so in the success event I just made the replace. Anyway, you have the right answer.